# Android/Eclipse Unable To Use xml layout file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I have created multiple XML files, but today I reopened my project and I am unable to set the content view to my newly created layout.  When I Type "R.layout" and look at the XML files it recommends; I see a list of XML files, but not the one that i want.  I have tried cleaning my project and rebuilding everything, but it didn't work.  I have also made sure that i'm not importing "Android.R". I am not sure why this is happening.  Thanks for your help.

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >  
</LinearLayout>
```

Tabs Class  java

```
package com.thenewboston.cfil360;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Tabs extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Where are the xml files? Make sure they're in res/layouts.

Comment: and make sure the file doesnt have an error in it

Comment: Yes they are in res/layouts and it is a freshly generated xml file. Does it matter if nothing is in it other than a linear layout?

Comment: @cfil360 Shouldn't matter. Could you post the layout? And also, does it give you an error if you manually type in the layout like `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutname)`, and then save the file?

Comment: Please don't post code or XML in comments.  It's difficult to read and doesn't help future visitors.  Paste it into your question instead.

Comment: @Simon sorry about that im new here.  I have posted the xml code in the original question.

Comment: And don't forget to refresh your project. Sometimes Eclipse is a bit strange.

Comment: @Peter do you mean clean your project?  Because yes i have done that.

Comment: No. There are three main different building steps which can be commanded via the Eclipse ADT - GUI. One is a simple build, one is clean and another one is "Refresh". While building and cleaning are related to compiling and deployment, "Refresh" recogizes things like file addition from outside eclipse and involves regenerating of the static classes which are autogenerated. It's within the context menu when right - clicking on the project.

Comment: @Peter no refreshing didn't work.

Comment: Puh. Another approach would be moving the gen - folder of your project, recreating the folder and do a fresh clean build.

Comment: @Peter Could there be something wrong with my activity class?

Comment: To check if your layout file is there and is setup properly, you can open your APK - File with a archive - program as ark (Linux) or WinZip. If you can't see your layout file, it contains error, the build process failes or something else obscure is happening.

Comment: No, it is not your Activity - class. If Eclipse can't autocomplete R.layout. to the layout that you added, there is something wrong either in the ide itself (and we know that eclipse got issues usually fixed by restarting it) or the layout file or the gen - folder (which could not be writeable for some reasons).

Comment: @Peter i was able to see the layout file after opening the .apk

Comment: have you tried `Fix Project Properties`?

Comment: Okay, then take a look at the generated R - class. It resides in your gen - folder and should contain an entry like: public static final class layout {public static final int com_facebook_friendpickerfragment = 0x7f030000; (from a sample of the Facebook - API). If no entry of the form your_package_yourlayout = 0x(some hex value), then the layout file can't be compiled. Try putting addtional content into the layout also, there could be issues with empty layouts.

Comment: @Peter I fixed it.  I don't know why it decided to work now but by adding a textview to the layout it worked.  Thanks for all your guys help.  Also how do i thumbs up your comment or whatever.